# Select nodes with XPath defined in attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

I would like to select nodes using the XPath which is defined in an attribute in the same XML document.
An example XML file:

```
<section count-node="table/row">
    <table>
        <row>row1</row>
        <row>row2</row>
        <row>row3</row>
    </table>
</section>
```

Now I would like to use XSLT to get the number of rows, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count({MY VALUE FOR @count-node}})"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
</xsl:template>
```

where

```
count({MY VALUE FOR @count-node}})
```

should be replaced by

```
count(/table/row)
```

when processing the stylesheet.
This should of course return

```
3
```

I cannot use '/table/row' in the stylesheet as I do not know the content of the  element. It does not have to be a table, or the table maybe nested.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which version of XSLT? If 1.0, which processor specifically?

Comment: I use XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-HE (9.4.0.7).

Comment: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/evaluate.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Note that Saxon-PE or EE is needed for `xsl:evaluate`.

Comment: @DanielHaley Okay, so I guess the answer is "can't be done" (without changing the processor)?

Comment: Is `count-node` an arbitrary XPath expression or is it guaranteed to be a simple `element1/element2/..../elementN` structure?  For simple expressions you might be able to finesse it if you `tokenize` on the `/` and then do the steps by hand using a recursive function that does `*[name() = $tokenN]` or similar.

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes, I suspect that the XPath expressions will remain simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your XPath expressions are rather simple, then the following might work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:variable name="expression" select="@count-node" as="node()"/>   
        <xsl:value-of select="count( 
            descendant::*[$expression = 
                          string-join(
                            (ancestor::*[.=$expression/../descendant::*]/name(), 
                             name()),
                            '/')] )"/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It counts all of the descendant elements who's computed XPath (relative from the `section`) is equal to the XPath from the `@count-node`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.
The expression ancestor::*[.=$expression/../descendant::*]/name() only returns empty strings for me unfortunately. I've changed your code into count(descendant::*[ends-with(string-join((ancestor::*/name(),name()),'/'),$expression)]) and this works for me, at least for the moment. 
Unfortunately table/row is now counted as long as the XPath ends with table/row, so nested items might also be returned. The expression is less strict.
Another problem, which I came across is that namespaces cannot be used in the expression.
Any thoughts on how I can solve these issues?

Comment: It is working for me, using the sample XML provided. Does it work against the sample XML that you posted or just not working with different inputs? If you are having issues with namespaces, you might want to use `local-name()` for the constructed XPath and possibly normalize the XPath from the attribute to remove any namespace-prefixes. It would be easier to help troubleshoot if you posted example XML that more closely matches your inputs.

Comment: You're quite right. The example I gave was a simplified version. I found the reason why it went wrong (an extra element was placed between table and row). Thanks!