# how make a Path select with variable?

Tags: variables, xslt, xpath

I try to select a value on an other Document with this way, but it doesn't work. I don't have the right path. What's the problem?

```
<xsl:template match="//element[@type='champ']/propriete[2]/text()">

    <xsl:variable name="chemin_data" select="." />

    <xsl:value-of select="document('data_rapport.xml')/$chemin_data"/> 

</xsl:template>
```

data_rapport.xml

```
<data>
    <client>value </client>
    <renseignement>
        <projet>  value </projet>
        <utilisateur> value <utilisateur>
    </renseignement>
</data>
```

`$chemin_data` contains a path like "`data/client`"

and for each `champ/propriete[2]` I try to have the good value.

Comment: Could you explain to us what you're trying to do? `document('data_rapport.xml')/$chemin_data` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: $chemin_data contains a path like "data/client"

and for each champ/propriete[2] i try to have the good value

Comment: This won't work since `$chemin_data` contains the *whole* context and not a partial one.

Comment: Why are you using a variable to try and construct the XPath?

Comment: i don't understand because when i try to do this : <xsl:value-of select="document('data_rapport.xml')/data/client"/> it's work @MarcusRickert

Comment: because it's not the same Data for each  //element[@type='champ']/propriete[2] @Horba

Comment: You need to post a full example of your problem. You're going to have to handle the different cases by checking for their existence. @user3710301

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020026/select-nodes-with-xpath-defined-in-attribute which is about a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dynamic XPath requires EXSLT - Dynamic http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
                extension-element-prefixes="dyn">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="chemin_data" select="'data/client'" />
        <xsl:variable name="data_rapport" select="document('data_rapport.xml')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(concat('$data_rapport', '/', $chemin_data))"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are a couple of things to remember with this solution:

- it requires your XSLT processor to support EXSLT - Dynamic (see documentation)
- your dynamic xpath has to be written as a string - otherwise you would already create a node set
- I used another variable for the document, due to string concatenation required to create your dynamic XPath
- and of course: you should try to avoid this as much as possible, since it's rather fragile and decreases performance, so only use it if really necessary

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a variable to construct XPath is a road you want to go down. You can access the nodes in the documet() as though it was a node.

XML data_rapport.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <client>clientValue </client>
    <renseignement>
        <projet>  value </projet>
        <utilisateur> value </utilisateur>
    </renseignement>
</data>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('data_rapport.xml')/data/client"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>clientValue
```